# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> t’ with actual type ‘[Text]’

Tags: string, haskell

I want to use the function `splitOn`:

```
Prelude Data.Text> splitOn "," "my,comma,separated,list"
```

But I receive the error message:

```
<interactive>:4:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the first argument of ‘splitOn’, namely ‘","’
      In the expression: splitOn "," "my,comma,separated,list"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = splitOn "," "my,comma,separated,list"

<interactive>:4:13: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the second argument of ‘splitOn’, namely
        ‘"my,comma,separated,list"’
      In the expression: splitOn "," "my,comma,separated,list"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = splitOn "," "my,comma,separated,list"
```

How to cast `[Char]` to `Text`?

EDIT: As Willem Van Onsem pointed out below, when starting `ghci`, I can pass on a paramter `-XOverloadedStrings`. I tried this by `stack ghci --ghc-options -XOverloadedString`, and then, using `splitOn` in the repl, it works fine

```
Prelude Data.Text> splitOn "," "my,text"
["my","text"]
```

However, when I instead try to load a script containing an call of `splitOn`, it still explains:

```
$ stack  ghci --ghc-options -XOverloadedStrings 
Using main module: 1. Package `tmp' component tmp:exe:tmp-exe with main-is file: /Users/gefeizhang/proj/haskell/tmp/app/Main.hs
Building all executables for `tmp' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
tmp> initial-build-steps (lib + exe)
The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: tmp

* * * * * * * *

Warning: Multiple files use the same module name:
         * Paths_tmp found at the following paths
           * /Users/gefei/proj/haskell/tmp/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.2.1.0/build/autogen/Paths_tmp.hs (tmp:lib)
           * /Users/gefei/proj/haskell/tmp/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-3.2.1.0/build/tmp-exe/autogen/Paths_tmp.hs (tmp:exe:tmp-exe)
* * * * * * * *

GHCi, version 8.10.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
    Prelude> :load app/Main.hs 
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, interpreted )
    
    app/Main.hs:8:13: error:
        • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
          Expected type: IO Text
            Actual type: [Text]
        • In a stmt of a 'do' block: list <- splitOn "," str
          In the expression:
            do str <- getLine
               list <- splitOn "," str
               print (str)
          In an equation for ‘main’:
              main
                = do str <- getLine
                     list <- splitOn "," str
                     print (str)
      |
    8 |     list <- splitOn "," str
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    app/Main.hs:8:25: error:
        • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Text’
          Expected type: Text
            Actual type: String
        • In the second argument of ‘splitOn’, namely ‘str’
          In a stmt of a 'do' block: list <- splitOn "," str
          In the expression:
            do str <- getLine
               list <- splitOn "," str
               print (str)
      |
    8 |     list <- splitOn "," str
      |                         ^^^
    Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Content of `app/Main.hs`:

```
module Main where

import Data.Text

main :: IO ()
main = do
    str <- getLine
    list = splitOn "," str
    print(list)
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the [**`OverloadedStrings`** extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_strings.html), for example by calling `ghci` with:

```
ghci -XOverloadedStrings
```

This extension will not interpret string literals *per se* as strings, it can be any type that is a member of the [**`IsString`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString). Here for example as [**`Text`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.5.0/docs/Data-Text.html#t:Text), so we can work with:

```
$ ghci -XOverloadedStrings
GHCi, version 9.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Data.Text
Prelude Data.Text> splitOn "," "my,comma,separated,list"
["my","comma","separated","list"]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works when I do `splitOn` interactively in the repl. But when I start ghci and then `:load` a module, it still complaints. See my edit above. Any idea?

Comment: @gefei: in the head of the file you can write `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` to enable this extension for the file.

Answer (score 1):

There are several versions of `splitOn` in the library.

If you ask [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org), you see there is a [version](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.4/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:splitOn) in package `Data.List.Split` that operates on plain lists, hence on `String` objects:

```
$ ghci
 λ> 
 λ> import qualified Data.List.Split as DLS
 λ> 
 λ> :type  DLS.splitOn
 DLS.splitOn :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
 λ> 
 λ> DLS.splitOn "," "Dublin,Rome,Paris,Prag"
 ["Dublin","Rome","Paris","Prag"]
 λ>
```

This works nicely on strings returned by `getLine`:

```
 λ> 
 λ> str <- getLine
 abc,def,ghi
 λ> 
 λ> DLS.splitOn "," str
 ["abc","def","ghi"]
 λ>
```